# Passport seems to forget the user session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Googled for a long time, haven't really found anything that's worked so far, so figured I'd ask here.

I'm trying to get sessions to work with Passport. I've completed the registration and login functionality, and that seems to work as it should.

The main issue is that req.isAuthenticated always returns false.
I've tried the usual things:

Made sure app.use(passport.session()) comes after the express-session configuration:

```
... 
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({ 
secret: 'somethingsomethingdarkside', 
cookie: { maxAge: 1209600000 }, 
saveUninitialized: false,
resave: false,
// using store session on MongoDB using express-session + connect
store: new MongoStore({
    url: configDB.url,
    collection: 'sessions'
  })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
...
```

I've gone into Passports request.js file, and done some debugging, and I can see that

```
this[property/*user*/] = user;
```

sets the values I want it to, and that I think it should.

Now, whenever I call

```
if (req.isAuthenticated())
```

it results in

```
this[property/*user*/] == undefined
```

returning false. I've also put in a log message telling me when the module is being initialized, and it only does it once, when the server starts.

As far as I can see, user.deserializeUser is never called either.

Kind of at my wits end here, anyone able to help me out?

Comment: did u check the value of `req.user`?

Comment: Also how are you defining `MongoStore`?

Comment: MongoStore is fine. I can see it adding a new session every time I log in (as well as every time I log out, don't know why.).

req.user is apparently undefined, and at first that was for a good reason (because I used sessionStorage like an idiot, not realizing it's a key-value store). Now though, it comes through req.body.user. How do I move it to req.user instead?


I add it the same way I do with login and register, but I suppose there's some Passport middleware that shaves down some of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been two or three kinds of stupid here, but finally, after many hours of late night coding (probably the main root of the issue), I managed to solve it.

@haywire Pointed me towards `req.user` which I saw came through blank, then I made sure to send it properly.

Then it wouldn't work, because I had tried to use a route middleware function that was supposed to check whether or not a user had logged in before I had defined it.

Coffee is a hell of a drug.